# cobertura-maven-plugin conflicts with FindBugs

Tags: maven, findbugs, cobertura

After updating `cobertura-maven-plugin` from **2.6** to **2.7** Cobertura plugin conflicts with FindBugs plugin. FindBugs plugin detects error in cobertura-instrumented code:

```
[INFO] Incorrect lazy initialization of static field pl.chilldev.sites.commons.ErrorCode.__cobertura_counters in pl.chilldev.sites.commons.ErrorCode.__cobertura_init() [pl.chilldev.sites.commons.ErrorCode] In ErrorCode.java
```

(everything works fine when Cobertura plugin verison is set to 2.6)

Just in case, FindBugs plugin version is 3.0.1.

Is it possible to set these plugins somehow to work together?

### Edit 1 (pom.xml)

This is `pom.xml` of main project directory (sub-modules contain only dependencies list):

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--
# This file is part of the pl.chilldev.sites.
#
# @copyright 2015 © by Rafał Wrzeszcz - Wrzasq.pl.
-->
<project
    xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd
">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <!-- core project settings -->
    <groupId>pl.chilldev.sites</groupId>
    <artifactId>sites</artifactId>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <!-- project meta info -->
    <name>ChillDev-Sites</name>
    <url><!-- TODO --></url>
    <description>Content sites storage service.</description>
    <inceptionYear>2015</inceptionYear>
    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>

    <organization>
        <name>Rafał Wrzeszcz - Wrzasq.pl</name>
        <url>http://wrzasq.pl/</url>
    </organization>

    <!-- plugins configuration -->
    <build>
        <pluginManagement>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.6</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <archive>
                            <index>true</index>
                            <manifest>
                                <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                            </manifest>
                            <manifestEntries>
                                <url>${project.url}</url>
                                <Specification-Title>${project.name}</Specification-Title>
                                <Specification-Version>${project.version}</Specification-Version>
                                <Specification-Vendor>Rafał Wrzeszcz - Wrzasq.pl; Chillout Development</Specification-Vendor>
                                <Implementation-Title>${project.name}</Implementation-Title>
                                <Implementation-Version>${project.version}</Implementation-Version>
                                <Implementation-Vendor>Rafał Wrzeszcz - Wrzasq.pl; Chillout Development</Implementation-Vendor>
                            </manifestEntries>
                        </archive>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </pluginManagement>

        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.3</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.7</source>
                    <target>1.7</target>
                    <compilerArgs>
                        <arg>-Xlint:all</arg>
                    </compilerArgs>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.7</version>
                <configuration>
                    <escapeString>\</escapeString>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>resources</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-pmd-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.4</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>check</goal>
                            <goal>cpd-check</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-checkstyle-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.15</version>
                <dependencies>
                    <!-- Maven Checkstyle plugin has a 6.1.1 version by default which is buggy -->
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>com.puppycrawl.tools</groupId>
                        <artifactId>checkstyle</artifactId>
                        <version>6.5</version>
                    </dependency>
                </dependencies>
                <configuration>
                    <configLocation>src/main/checkstyle/checkstyle.xml</configLocation>
                    <propertyExpansion>checkstyle.project.basedir=${project.basedir}</propertyExpansion>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>check</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-site-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.4</version>
                <dependencies>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.apache.maven.doxia</groupId>
                        <artifactId>doxia-module-markdown</artifactId>
                        <version>1.6</version>
                    </dependency>

                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>lt.velykis.maven.skins</groupId>
                        <artifactId>reflow-velocity-tools</artifactId>
                        <version>1.1.1</version>
                    </dependency>

                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.apache.velocity</groupId>
                        <artifactId>velocity</artifactId>
                        <version>1.7</version>
                    </dependency>
                </dependencies>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-pdf-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.3</version>
                <!-- TODO:
                    - fix rendering of company and project logos
                    - add UTF-8 font
                -->
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>site</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>pdf</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-source-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.4</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>jar-no-fork</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-javadoc-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.10.2</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>jar</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>findbugs-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <effort>Max</effort>
                    <threshold>Low</threshold>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>check</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>

        <resources>
            <resource>
                <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
                <filtering>true</filtering>
            </resource>
        </resources>
    </build>

    <!-- reporting plugins -->
    <reporting>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-project-info-reports-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.8</version>
                <configuration>
                    <dependencyLocationsEnabled>false</dependencyLocationsEnabled>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-javadoc-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.10.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <show>private</show>
                    <excludePackageNames>test.pl.chilldev.sites.*</excludePackageNames>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-pmd-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.4</version>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-checkstyle-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.15</version>
                <configuration>
                    <configLocation>src/main/checkstyle/checkstyle.xml</configLocation>
                    <propertyExpansion>checkstyle.project.basedir=${project.basedir}</propertyExpansion>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-jxr-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.5</version>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-report-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.18.1</version>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>cobertura-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <!-- TODO: 2.7 doesn't work well with Findbugs -->
                <version>2.6</version>
                <configuration>
                    <formats>
                        <format>html</format>
                    </formats>
                    <instrumentation>
                        <excludes>
                            <exclude>test/**/*.class</exclude>
                        </excludes>
                    </instrumentation>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>findbugs-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <effort>Max</effort>
                    <threshold>Low</threshold>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </reporting>

    <!-- project dependencies -->
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.12</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <!-- components of the project -->
    <modules>
        <module>sites-backend</module>
        <module>sites-commons</module>
        <module>sites-core</module>
        <module>sites-frontend</module>
        <module>sites-rpc-client-backend</module>
        <module>sites-rpc-client-frontend</module>
        <module>sites-rpc-service</module>
    </modules>
</project>
```

### Edit 2 (ErrorCode.java)

```java
package pl.chilldev.sites.commons;

/**
 * JSON-RPC error codes.
 */
public class ErrorCode
{
    /**
     * Dummy code that represents successful operation - should not be used at all.
     */
    public static final int OK = 0;

    /**
     * No entity of specified ID exists.
     */
    public static final int NO_ENTITY = 1;
}
```

Comment: Could you show us your pom definition?

Comment: Sure, I edited the question post.

The one from the post works right now - when I change `cobertura-maven-plugin` version to 2.7 it breaks FindBugs plugin check.

Comment: Could you also list ErrorCode.java?

Comment: Added to the post. But I tried removing this class - it's just the first one FindBugs finds. When I delete this one, it posts same error about next one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Cobertura 2.7 alters `project.build.outputDirectory` in order to produce report for integration tests (new kind of report introduced in 2.7). In the next step Findbugs checks violations not on just compiled classes but on instrumented.

See bug:

http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/MCOBERTURA-203

As a workaround you can override `classFilesDirectory`:

```
...
<build>
...
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>findbugs-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <effort>Max</effort>
                <threshold>Low</threshold>
                <classFilesDirectory>${project.build.outputDirectory}</classFilesDirectory>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>check</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
...
</build>
...
```

Another solution is to skip integration tests report and proceed with unit tests report only:

http://mojo.codehaus.org/cobertura-maven-plugin/usage.html#Using_different_reports

Comment: Thanks a lot! That's really the case.

However after investigating the issue, I think such workarounds is not a good solution, as the real issue, with instrumented classes remains. So I decided to downgrate to **2.6** and stay with it for now. Passing Maven build for the price of corrupted (not literally, but modified) binaries is not worth doing this.

Comment: Yes, Great answer. (y)

Comment: Additionally, if you have findbugs as both a `build` and `reporting` plugin, make sure to put the `cobertura` reporting plugin as the first entry in the reporting plugin list. Otherwise the findbugs `build` configuration is run after your `reporting` configuration, overwriting and thus thrashing your site's report.

Answer (score 1):

If you force findbugs to run in the "compile" phase instead of the "test" phase, it will cause findbugs to run before the code is instrumented by cobertuar, thus solving the issue as described by Mateusz Balbus. This findbugs maven configuration works for me:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>findbugs-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.5</version>
    <configuration>
        <executions>
            <execution>
                <id>findbugs-check</id>
                <phase>compile</phase>
                <goals>
                    <goal>check</goal>
                </goals>
            </execution>
        </executions>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Answer (score -2):

Need to know about your project structure first.

I think your problem can be solved by using **transitive dependency** but not sure.

It does two things.

1. Set a default version for dependencies in submodules/child projects
2. override the version of transitive dependencies

*it does override a specified value in a transitive dependency.*

The enforcer plugin does not ignore the **dependencyManagement**. But is unable to recognize the discrepancy since the **transitive dependency's** version was altered before it went to work.

Here is a nice article : You can go through it:
http://andydennie.com/2012/08/02/maven-enforcer-plugin-vs-dependencymanagement/

And another source: http://maven.apache.org/enforcer/maven-enforcer-plugin/

Thanks.

Comment: Either you didn't understand question, or I didn't understand the answer... The problem is not in conflicting dependencies, the problem is, that two build plugins can not co-exist peacefully in same build. I want to use BOTH. They fail even in flat-structured project, without modules.

Comment: Yes, It is miss-understanding. Mateusz Balbus's answer is correct although this answer is not wrong but can't fix this issue. @RafałWrzeszcz should i delete this answer? I think not bcz someone can get information from this too.